# Solving partial differential equation $u_x + 2xu_y + (2x - 6)u = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the differential equation above by separating the variables. Thus, I let $u(x,y) = X(x)Y(y)$. As such, $u_x = X'(x)Y(y)$ and $u_y = Y'(y)X(x)$.

The differential equation above can then be rewritten as:
$X'(x)Y(y) + 2xX(x)Y'(y) + (2x - 6)X(x)Y(y) = 0$

However, I find myself stuck after this step as I'm unable to separate the variables and shift all the functions/variables with x to 1 side of the equation and all the functions/variables with y to the other side of the equation.

Some help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: $$X'Y + 2xXY'+(2x-6)XY = 0 \implies -\frac{Y'}{Y} = \frac{X'+(2x-6)X}{2xX}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$u_x + 2xu_y = (6-2x)u$$
Why not the method of characteristics ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

The Charpit-Lagrange system of characteristic ODEs is :
$$\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2x}=\frac{du}{(6-2x)u}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2x}$ :
$$y-x^2=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{2x}=\frac{6dx-dy}{6-2x}=\frac{du}{(6-2x)u}\quad;\quad d(6x-y)=\frac{du}{u}$
$$u\:e^{y-6x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$u\:e^{y-6x}=F(y-x^2)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$\boxed{u(x,y)=e^{6x-y}F(y-x^2)}$$
If some boundary condition was specified in the wording of the problem one could determine the function $F$ in order to find the particular solution satisfying both the PDE and the boundary condition.

Comment: $+1$. Nice. $(*)(*)$.